# Split separated string in XML and write values to different variables via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm searching for a solution to transform metadata within a XML file to variables within a flat file. This should be done by converting the XML with an XSL File.

An example XML file is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recordset><items><ID>1</ID><Type>IVD</Type><No>123456</No><Date>2021-05-28</Date><Positions><PosNo>10;20;30;50</PosNo></Positions></items></recordset>
```

The desired output would be:

```
ID = "1"
Type = "IVD"
HeaderNo = "123456"
Date = "2021-05-28"
Pos[1] = 10
Pos[2] = 20
Pos[3] = 30
Pos[4] = 50
```

The first part wouldn't be the problem i think. But how to realize the last part? The PosNo has to be splitted by the character ";" and each value has been written down as single line with an automatic array counter.

Your help would really be appreciated. If possible it should be able to run within xslt 1.0.
Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why is ID and HeaderNo values in quotes, but the Pos not?

Comment: Hint: to number the tokens, use a 2nd parameter initialized to 1 and increment it by 1 in each recursive call. Alternatively, if your processor supports the `str:tokenize()` extension function, you can simply use `position()`.

Comment: @MadsHansen string vs. number?

Comment: Sorry, the Pos values have to be in quotes as well.

Can you perhaps give me an example on how to realize it michael?